# Accidentally renamed /var root directory to etc/var

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux

Please help
I accidentally renamed /var root directory to etc/var. Now I am not able to login through putty and filezilla.
What should I do? Please help

Comment: Try remote access via a VNC client - in case VNC is enabled in the server and was already running before you did this.

Comment: @harrymc The client has a redhat server and the root user was given the rights to access the server through putty and filezilla. Now I moved the /var folder to /etc folder. Can I resolve this issue?

Comment: As I said : Try remote desktop via VNC and hope the service is already launched and does not use /var. But you will probably need username+password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't log in remotely you have to go on site or at least ask someone locally :-)

Reboot the server with some live linux distribution, mount your server hard drive and simply move var back with something like "cd /etc && mv var /" Hopefully permissions were not changed and you will be online in few minutes.

Never log again on FileZilla as root.

You could:

1 - put a live linux distribution, something like [fedora live](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB) and reboot your system with it. This will boot your server from a new operatin system wich is installad on usb.

2 - mount phisical hard drives. Should be easy also from the fedora graphical interface.

3- move back /var from /etc where you accidentally dropped it. As you are a novice try with nautilus file manager, also from the fedora graphic interface.

Comment: I am completely novice to this. Can you please help me with the exact steps.

Comment: So, try with the graphical interface because with text interfaces you must be able to identify drives and you have to kwnow commands.

Comment: Which graphical interface should I use. Cause I am not able to login in filezilla

Comment: You can't restore the system from filezilla, as you can't log into the system. You must do it locally

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I need to inform client regarding this issue. Because I don't think I can access server locally. But just last question. Is this recoverable???

Comment: Sure it is. If you follow the steps as decribed you will recover it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not clear, Please clearly mention your problem..
Os take the backup of existing directory as a root and mount it in the right directory, after mounting it copy the data in this directory.

Comment: /var is the root directory. In filezilla I mistakenly renamed/moved /var to /etc. Now I am not able to login in filezilla and putty to move the folder back in its right place. This is client's server and can I have any solution without notifying the client